# PHP get external data, but if content's longer than x do this?

Tags: php, html

There is probably a better way of doing this and if so please let me know but I am trying to get data from an external website (this is just for a personal website I wanted to make myself for ease of tracking stuff + I like to learn).

The issue i am having is I am using xpath to get data from a specific div. The issue arises only in a very small occurrence when the div is not there. I will use a URL in the below that this is not working on:

```
<?php
// exchange line 1
  $url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/farstcoin/";
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// exchange line 1 name
  $elementsname1 = $xpath->query('//*[@id="markets-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/text()');
  $exchange = $dom->saveHTML($elementsname1->item(0));
  $exchangelower = strtolower($exchange);
  $exchangelowerspace = str_replace(' ',"-",$exchangelower);
// exchange line 1 pair
  $elementpair = $xpath->query('//*[@id="markets-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a/text()');
  $pairing = $dom->saveHTML($elementpair->item(0));
// exchange line 1 volume
  $elementvolume = $xpath->query('//*[@id="markets-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]');
  $volume = $dom->saveHTML($elementvolume->item(0));
// exchange line 1 price
  $elementprice = $xpath->query('//*[@id="markets-table"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]');
  $exchangeprice = $dom->saveHTML($elementprice->item(0));
```

As i am doing this for a load of pages this worked best for me but this one issue is really rare but annoying. I am using the below to display the data:

```
<div class="col-md-12">Price:<?php echo $exchangeprice; ?></div>
<div class="col-md-12">Volume:<?php echo $volume; ?></div>
<div class="col-md-12">Pair:<?php echo $pairing; ?></div>
```

For this one example it's pulling the whole of the coinmarketcap.com website in and displaying it on my page, in other examples it pulls the data as needed.

Is there a way of me saying if the string is longer than xxx characters its failed or?

Thanks!

Comment: [`int strlen ( string $string )` — Get string length](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: `if(strlen($simething)>$xxx)echo 'too long, failed?';`

Comment: Thanks guys this worked. I just did an "if(strlen" after the pull and made it change the tag if true to be empty! Again thanks a ton!

Comment: You do know coinmarketcap.com has an API right? https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Comment: @Pablo I do yeah, but some of the data you can't get via the API such as the exchanges each coin is on :( I do get most info from the API tho. Thanks!